# Entity Framework Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Where is the cycle?

Tags: t-sql, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, referential-integrity

I'm getting the error in the title when I try to create the database for my entity framework code first database

I understand what the message error mean (maybe not??), and I know how to disable the cascade delete for that particular property

What I want to know is which properties are causing the error, because I only see one cascade delete in the table

[Here is a gist to the generated sql script that gives me the error](https://gist.github.com/rodrigojuarez/7f2861e54beb27c067496f9b80e434ed)

Answer (score 1):

If I run your script I get

Msg 1785, Level 16, State 0, Line 472
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.WorkOrders_dbo.Customers_CustomerId' on table 'WorkOrders' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 472
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Caused by

```
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WorkOrders] ADD CONSTRAINT
       [FK_dbo.WorkOrders_dbo.Customers_CustomerId] FOREIGN KEY 
       ([CustomerId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Customers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

I usually turn cascade deletes off.  I like to know when things are deleted.

The cycle may be Customer, WorkOrder, Alarm, Customer,